# UITableViewCell on selection highlighting color

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have implemented tableview in my viewcontroller. I have not given any cell selection style.

What problem I am facing is, when I click on any of the cell it becomes gray. Normally what should happen is only background should become gray and not the whole cell. But here whole cell becomes gray.

Can anyone provide solution for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please attach screen shot of the selected cell and the corresponding interface builder tab.

Comment: If you do not want the Gray Color then just set the selection style to none.

Comment: I think he wants it but the text becomes grey too - that might be the problem.

Comment: Yes exactly! I want it. But why my buttons becomes gray. Text remains black.

Comment: Selected row looks too bad. :(
I want only background should become gray. not my buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to implement your custom selection style as following steps.

First, you will want to disable the default selection behaviour:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```

Second, override setHighlighted method (when user tap the cell and not yet raise his finger):

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    self.YOURVIEW.background = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Third, override setSelected method (when user tapped and raise his finger):

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    self.YOURVIEW.background = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Finally, you will want to deselect the cell in your tableview at a proper time by calling:

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:];
```

Comment: Got error for super keyword. Because it's my viewcontroller not tableviewcontroller.

Comment: @Gati You will need to set them in a subclass of the UITableViewCell.

Comment: There are some copy-paste errors in your answer (setSelected instead of setHighlighted), and I'm afraid, calling super's setSelected will cause the issue again, so it should be avoided.

Comment: @halakala You are right I have edited the answer. This code works for me so I think it's better to call super unless there is a good reason.

Comment: I am not getting guys. How I will get my custom cell of tableview in above methods.

Comment: Hey now I got you. Thanks for your answer.
But now my problem is slight different. Highlighting colour looks proper. my buttons not becoming gray. But now that gray colour not went out. It stays in background. How to remove it?

Comment: On row click I am moving it to detail screen. after coming back on front screen that gray colour which is in background should be removed. But it's not.

Comment: I got that solution also! Reload table and On cellForRowAtIndexPath, I have reset my cell background colour.
Thanks a lot guys! :)

Comment: @Gati reload table is heavy, you can try the last code of my answer by deselecting the tableView.

Comment: Yes correct I will do it as per your answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your cell's `setSelected` method don't call the super's one, and implement your own solution. (Like graying out only the background view.)

Comment: I am not getting you. Can you please provide example code for it?

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setSelected:animated:

Comment: setSelected  = YES. 
still same thing happening. :(

Comment: [cell setSelected:YES];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76532/discussion-between-halakala-and-gati).